# Django function to require that user not be logged in

Tags: python, django, authentication

I want to do the inverse of **@login_required** for my login and register views.
Here is what I want to do (but doesn't work)

```
def amIAuth(request)
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect(account)

def login(request):
    amIAuth(request)
    ....
```

Comment: In what way does it not work (what behavior does it show), and what do you mean by "the inverse of login_required"?

Comment: you should be able to write you own decorator "@" function; search for how to do that, or hopefully someone who knows how responds to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you have it doesn't work because login() doesn't do anything with the return value.

The proper way to do this a decorator, much like **@login_required**:

```
def not_loggedin_required(function):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return redirect(account) # redirect to profile page
        else:
            return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrap

@not_loggedin_required
def login(request):
    ...
```

Comment: where do i have to write not_loggedin_required? do I have to import something?

Comment: You can either write it in the same file above your login() and register() views (as I've shown here), or you can write it in a separate file (say, decorators.py) and import it at the top with "from decorators import not_loggedin_required"

Comment: I wrote exactely what you write and I have still access to my login view when I'm log

Comment: Can you try putting print statements or some other form of logging in the if and else branches to see which one happens?

Comment: @TotuDoum apologies, I just edited to fix a critical bug. Can you try the answer as it is written now?